# How does the Vaishnava commentators interpret 'NAda-Upasana' prescribed in Srimad-Bhagavatam?

Tags: vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, yoga

Srimad-Bhagavatam is treated as a scripture praising Lord Hari and showing the path of Devotion.

The 12th Canto (Chapter 6, Slokas 37-38) advise the anAhata-nAda upasana as a way of reaching the Ultimate Goal.

How do the Vaishnava commentators explain this?